# How to read data from an XML file from a URL

Tags: java, xml, javafx

Okay so I need to parse some weather data from a URL and it looks like this:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

```
//Some stuff saying where the data is from

<meteodata time="2017-05-10 15:03:00" ts="1494417780">
<data id="temp" name="Temperatuur" unit="&deg;C">1.75266666667</data>
<data id="humid" name="Niiskus" unit="%">77.868</data>
<data id="baro" name="&Otilde;hur&otilde;hk" unit="hPa">1006.958</data>
<data id="wind_dir" name="Tuule suund" unit="&deg;">125.647436610365</data>
<data id="wind_len" name="Tuule kiirus" unit="m/s">3.11000784765891</data>
<data id="lux" name="Valgustatus" unit="lx">-</data>
<data id="sole" name="Kiirgusvoog" unit="W/m<sup>2</sup>">593.985982297</data>
<data id="gamma" name="Radioaktiivsus" unit="&micro;Sv/h">-</data>
<data id="precip" name="Sademed" unit="mm/s">0</data>
</meteodata>
```

But I don't really know how to read this into a project in a way that would let me translate it into a fxml display with an update button. For reference I'm using IntelliJ and the data is just temperature, humidity and so on.

Comment: I think that the best way to create a user interface will be parsing this XML and building view programmatically or filling FXML based template. I don't think that converting XML to FXML will give you expected results.

Comment: ^ and you could create two simple bean classes, one for meteodata, and one for data, and use JAXB to unmarshal the xml into your beans. Or use Jackson.